# Placeholder animado

Tags: html, css, placeholder

ola encontrei essa resposta https://jsfiddle.net/2a1kvcn6/1/ porem não consigo manter o placeholder como titulo, assim que digito algo ele some, desta forma a caixa fica sem identificação

```css
.inputAnimado{
  margin: 10px 25px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #1abc9c;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #1abc9c 4%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #1abc9c 4%);
  background-position: -200px 0;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #0e6252;
}

.inputAnimado:focus, .inputAnimado:valid {
 box-shadow: none;
 outline: none;
 background-position: 0 0;
}

.inputAnimado::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.inputAnimado:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder, .inputAnimado:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #1abc9c;
 font-size: 11px;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
 transform: translateY(-20px);
 visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Não quero sumir ao digitar" class="inputAnimado" required>
```

Comment: Por favor, entre em [edit] e adicione o seu código. Se for apenas HTML, CSS e JavaScript, pode adicioná-lo pressionando `Ctrl+M` no editor da pergunta.

Comment: Sim o teste foi feito no chrome

Comment: o problema e que ao digitar no input o placeholder some, gostaria que ele ficasse.

Comment: Ok, estava entendendo errado o problema, desculpe-me.

Comment: Perfeito acha que consegue me da uma luz, ja pesquisei não acho a solução

Comment: O comportamento por defeito do texto no `placeholder` é desaparecer quando é inserido texto no campo.

Comment: exatamente, se ele desaparece a informção do campo input fica sem descrição

Answer (score 3):

Eu acredito que utilizando o `placeholder` não há como fazer devido ao seu funcionamento padrão, que é sumir quando o comprimento do valor do `input` é maior que zero. Uma maneira não tão simples, mas nada complexa, é posicionar o `label` referente ao `input` sobre o mesmo, simulando o `placeholder` e quando o `input` receber o foco mover o `label` para cima, na posição do título.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
$(() => {

  $("input").on("focus", function(event) {
    const div = $(this).parent(".input-field");
    const label = div.children("label");
    
    label.css("top", "-10px");
  });
  
  $("input").on("blur", function(event) {
    const div = $(this).parent(".input-field");
    const label = div.children("label");
    
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
      label.css("top", "12px");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.input-field {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.input-field input {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #1abc9c;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #1abc9c 4%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #1abc9c 4%);
  background-position: -200px 0;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #0e6252;
}

.input-field input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.input-field label {
  color: #9e9e9e;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field">
  <input id="name" type="text" class="validate">
  <label for="name">Nome</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field">
  <input id="lastname" type="text" class="validate">
  <label for="lastname">Sobrenome</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field">
  <input id="email" type="text" class="validate">
  <label for="email">E-mail</label>
</div>
```

Comment: perfeito anderson, não ta complexo não ta simples entendivel, agradeço muiiito

Comment: Deve haver uma maneira mais simples ou mais elegante, mas estou com o cérebro travado e não consigo em pensar nada melhor. Se quiser, pode manter a pergunta aberta para ver se aparece outra solução.

Comment: pensei que ia ser mil maravilhas mas agora estou com outro problema kkkkkk, quando o angular carrega os dados vindo da banco, a label não sai da frente misturando os textos

Comment: o evento esta como onfocus, ja tentei onchange, tambem nada

Comment: Acredito que isso será melhor discutido em outra pergunta, colocando o código do angular, este que você fez para placeholder e uma imagem de como fica o resultado, se não for possível executar o código no snippet do SOpt.

Answer (score 0):

O seu código CSS está correto, o que está faltando é a tag `required` no HTML do seu input,de acordo com o exemplo para acontecer a animação ela é necessária. O seu código irá ficar assim:

```
<input class="inputAnimado" type="text" placeholder="Vou sumir ao digitar" required>
```

Agora se você quer que funcione em todos os casos, independente do `required` ou não, você deve alterar o seu CSS. Retire o `.inputAnimado:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder` :

```
.inputAnimado:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #1abc9c;
    font-size: 11px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    visibility: visible !important;
 }
```

O que acontece é que o `:valid` é usado para validar de acordo com a tag `type` do HTML, como sem o required o seu campo de texto é sempre válido ele não vai entrar e sair da animação, vai estar sempre animado. Retirando o `:valid` a animação só irá depender do `:focus`, ou seja, ele só ficará ativado quando houver interação com aquele campo.

Comment: Mas o texto continua sumindo desta forma, não?

Comment: a sim tinha esquecido de colocar o required, mas mesmo assim esse não eo foco do meu problema, acontece que quando digito o primeiro caracter no input, o placeholder some, na minha app esses campos são preenchidos com dados do BD, se o placeholder não ficar como titulo, a informação fica sem identificação.