# Mudar Placeholder no Focus com CSS é possível?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, input, ui

Imagina que eu tenho um `input` para o número de telefone, mas que quando o usuário focar nele eu quero mudar o texto do `placeholder`, por exemple de *"telefone"* para *"apenas números"*.

É possível fazer isso com CSS no `:focus` por exemplo. Ou tenho que usar JS?

```html
Quando focar nesse inpute gostaria de trocar o texto do placeholder para por exemplo "apenas números"
<br><br>
<input type="tel" placeholder="telefone" name="" id="">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Primeiro método

Você pode usar javascript, peguei o evento focus e seto o valor no placeholder e o onblur para retornar ao valor anterior, e você escolhe qual o elemento você quer fazer este efeito utilizando o querySelector.

```js
var elemento = document.querySelector("input");
elemento.onfocus = function(){
    elemento.placeholder = "apenas número";
};
elemento.onblur = function(){
    elemento.placeholder = "telefone";
};
```

```html
Quando focar nesse inpute gostaria de trocar o texto do placeholder para por exemplo "apenas números"
<br><br>
<input type="tel" placeholder="telefone" name="" id="">
```

## Segundo método

Criei uma nova forma na qual você vai preocupar com o javascript apenas uma vez, basta colocar a classe alter-placeholder no elemento e os atributos placeholder-focus e placeholder-blur definindo o texto, veja um exemplo:

```js
var elemento = document.querySelector(".alter-placeholder");
elemento.onfocus = function(){
 elemento.placeholder = this.getAttribute('data-placeholder-focus');
};
elemento.onblur  = function(){
 elemento.placeholder = this.getAttribute('data-placeholder-blur');
};
```

```html
Quando focar nesse inpute gostaria de trocar o texto do placeholder para por exemplo "apenas números"
<br><br>
<input 
placeholder="telefone" 
data-placeholder-blur="telefone" 
data-placeholder-focus="apenas número" 
class="alter-placeholder" 
type="tel" name="" id="">
```

Comment: Vitor obrigado pela contribuição, acredito que esse código vai me ajudar até em outras ocasiões! []´s

Comment: Eu recomendaria usar `data-placeholder-blur` e `data-placeholder-focus` pois `placeholder-blur` e `placeholder-focus` não são atributos válidos, tornando sua página um documento HTML5 inválido.

Comment: Obrigado @fernandosavio, você tem razão, editei a minha resposta

Answer (score 6):

Não conheço uma forma <s>decente</s> elegante de fazer isto sem usar js, mas se estiver com muita vontade de utilizar apenas css, a <s>gambetosa</s> alternativa abaixo deve quebrar o galho:

```css
.input-holder{
  position: relative;
}

.input-holder .placeholderson{
  color: currentColor;
  opacity: .7;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  padding: 2px;
  display:none;
}
.input-holder input::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.input-holder input:focus:placeholder-shown + .placeholderson.focused-placeholder{
  display:block
}
.input-holder input:not(:focus):placeholder-shown  + .placeholderson.focused-placeholder + .placeholderson.blurred-placeholder {
  display:block
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<label class="input-holder">
  <input type="tel" name="" id="" placeholder="....">
  <div class="focused-placeholder placeholderson">Somente números...</div>
  <div class="blurred-placeholder placeholderson">Telefone...</div>
</label>
```

Comment: Por incrível que pareça, essa é a forma que mais se aproxima do *semanticamente ideal* no HTML. Você tem os elementos *corretos* fazendo seus respectivos papéis, a única coisa é que não são exibidos da forma natural - e quase sempre não são, o CSS é justamente para isso. Você pode ter o `<label>` informando a finalidade do campo e um `<span>` alertando as restrições; se eles forem exibidos sobre o `<input>`, que mal tem? Inclusive é o que o Material usa para animar o `placeholder`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203018/5878

Comment: Interessante @AndersonCarlosWoss... Resolvi o problema do required com o seletor `:placeholder-shown` e adicionando um placeholder transparente. Quando o placeholder desaparece da o mesmo resultado que o `:invalid`

Answer (score 3):

Só com CSS acredito que não, mas com JS dá, inclusive inline:

```html
Quando focar nesse inpute gostaria de trocar o texto do placeholder para por exemplo "apenas números"
<br><br>
<input type="tel" placeholder="telefone" name="telefone" id="" onfocus='this.placeholder="apenas números"' onblur='this.placeholder="telefone"'>
```

No `onfocus` mudo para o placeholder alternativo, e no `onblur` volto ao original. O placeholder é uma propriedade do elemento e creio que só possa ser alterado via JavaScript.

Comment: Valeu mais uma vez Sam

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o pseudo-elemento `before` de uma `div` com `contentEditable` `true` para conseguir uma aproximação do resultado desejado apenas com `CSS`:

```css
div[type=tel][contentEditable=true] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  background-color: white;
  background-color: -moz-field;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;  
  font: -moz-field;
  font: -webkit-small-control;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  width: 398px;
}

div[type=tel]::before {
  color: #909090;
  font-weight: 300;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

div[type=tel]:empty:not(:focus)::before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

div[type=tel]:empty:focus::before {
  content: attr(data-hint);
}
```

```html
<div type="tel" contentEditable=true data-placeholder="telefone" data-hint="apenas números"></div>
```

Comment: Bem legal, pouco código bom uso do css, o problema é que no Submit não pega o "valor" do "input" se não me engano.

Comment: @hugocsl é, acho que realmente nesse caso não pega mesmo, então provavelmente não seja um bom uso com o `form`

Comment: Fica valendo mais para curiosidade pra quem não manja muito de pseudo elemento e pseudo classe ver um bom uso. apesar de não funcionar por forme pode servir pra outras coisas no front..

Comment: @hugocsl na real tem um pseudo-elemento [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) também, mas não consegui descobrir se dá pra trocar o conteúdo dele pelo CSS

Comment: `::placeholder` me parece que seja apenas para estilizar a tipografia do texto do `placeholder=" "` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder se o input aceitasse pseudo-elemento direto no input::after, daria para falsear o placeholder

Comment: Olha ai os atributos que o  ::placeholder reconhece https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/#article-header-id-4

Comment: @hugocsl é, realmente, só estilo. O que podemos esperar é que, como é experimental, talvez incluam algo mais depois